# Looking for: jQuery-Plugin for tab support in a textarea

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm looking for a plugin or lightweight js-editor, which supports tabs in a textarea.

Anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about, for instance : [Tabs in Textarea Plugin for Javascript jQuery](http://teddevito.com/demos/textarea.html) *(there is a demo, and some explanations, and links to other resources)*

Comment: @Joerg : you're welcome ; have fun !